# Accessing MySQL database from Delphi asynchronously

Tags: mysql, delphi, iocp

How to access MySQL database from Delphi asynchronously?

Thread that executes select statement should not be blocked. Creating background threads for each active select statement is not a solution too, because on heavy loaded system this would create to many threads and would lead to performance problems.

IOCP (i/o completion ports) is exactly what I need. But I don't know how to use this technology with MySQL from Delphi.

Comment: Why do you feel IOCP is the right way for you. Do you think that executing hundreds of queries *concurrently* is fine for your server ? Yes, clients will be happy, that they don't have running hundreds of threads, but what about server if there will be many clients running at the same time with so many requests ? Consider using thread pool and having queue for queries.

Comment: heavy load = performance problems? Classic solution: add more performance :)

Comment: @TLama, I want to extract the maximum possible performance from my hardware. Imagine situation, when I have one web server and several database servers connected to a local network. If there were hundreds of threads running on my web server then significant amount of CPU time would be spent on switching between them. But why this work has to be done when it's not necessary? Web server should serve web pages, but not switch between threads. I want to implement what node.js does, but on Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of application where it actually makes sense to execute queries asynchronously, then do it. Let the server deal with the concurrency issue. You can easily configure the server.

For example, take a look at [`innodb_thread_concurrency`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) and [`max_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections).

Comment: You didn't answer how to execute query asynchronously from Delphi without blocking thread that initiated the query and without creating separate thread for that. Please look at my comment under the question .

Comment: @user1439838, you seemed to be asking which of these methods you propose. I pick "Creating background threads for each active select statement".

Comment: I would like to get the same performance as node.js has, but in Delphi application. A lot of concurrent connections is not a problem, but a lot of idle threads waiting for some event - is the problem.